# Is it possible to do an md5 check without writing to the filesystem?

Tags: c#, md5, filestream, memorystream

Basically I am doing the following:

1. Download an encrypted file from a web site into a MemoryStream
2. Decrypt the file
3. Write the decrypted file out to the file system
4. Read it back into memory again as a FileStream
5. Calculate the MD5 and check it.
6. Send the file to the printer.

Here is my code:

```
private async void DownloadFileToBePrinted()
{

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        var data = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(new Uri(Url));                

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
        {                    
            valid = DecodeFile(ms);

        }
    }
}

private bool DecodeFile(MemoryStream stream)
{
    bool valid = true;

    try
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            stream.Position = 0;
            var str = reader.ReadToEnd();

            File.WriteAllBytes(FILE_TO_BE_PRINTED, this.Decode(str));

            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                using (var fs = File.OpenRead(FILE_TO_BE_PRINTED))
                {
                    var hash = md5.ComputeHash(fs);

                    if (ByteToHex(hash) != FileDetails.MD5) // check against stored md5
                        valid = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        valid = false;
    }
    return (valid);
}
```

This seems a bit inefficient, apart from the fact that it is a requirement that a file not be written to the filesystem if it can be avoided.

So I am wondering if it is possible to do this without writing the file out to the file system?  If so how?

Comment: Could you post your current code?

Comment: Code added. Basically I'm fine once I have a FileStream.  I'm just not sure how to get there without writing out to the file system first (or even if its possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the MD5 without a FileStream like so:

```
byte[] decoded = this.Decode(str);
var md5 = MD5.Create();
md5.ComputeHash(decoded);
```

Comment: That looks like what I want.  Except that FileStream doesn't have a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Comment: @AdamJones The issue is that you need the FileStream for printing, not hash calculation, right? Because you can calculate the hash from a byte array.

Comment: Yep, that does solve my problem for the MD5 check.  I might be able to solve that printer problem on my own now. Thanks. :)